# DataGridView - Delete items with ContextMenu

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenu, datasource

I am currently developing an `DataGridView` to store PDF-Files via Drag and Drop.
The user is able to d'n'd the file into the `DataGridView` and the PDF is stored to an container.

Then I wanted to realize a `ContextMenu` which allows the user to open or delete the PDF by right clicking on it and selecting the targeted option.

The option "Open" is working fine by using the `HitTest(x, y)` with the `CursorPosition`.

My problem is, that as you see the "Delete" button is placed in the cell bellow and the `HitTest(x, y)` will deliver me the cell right below, which is not my goal.

**What I have tried**

I've tried it by catching the `CellContentClick` and `Click` events, but those are not triggered by right clicking the cell. Also the option by saving the last entered cell by catching the `CellMouseEnter` event is not working propably

***Is there any posibility to get to know which cell was right clicked?***

Comment: Can you get the top left most position of the ContextMenu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your dataGridView enable the Single Cell Selection property and then on click of your context menu you can get the selected cell

You can get the selected cell by

```
private void dataGridView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    }
}
```